# how if the status is active then the button is also active in codeigniter

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a problem, if status_sk = terbit  then the button is active and if status_sk =on process then the button is off, in codeigniter.
please help me

```
                foreach ($record->result() as $skl) {
           $status=$skl->status_sk;
                echo "<tr><td>$no</td>
                      <td>$skl->nama_ptk</td>
              <td>$skl->no_sk_kepsek</td>
                      <td >$skl->status_sk</td>
              <?php if ($status=='SK TERBIT'):?>
              <td >".anchor('ptk2/cetak_one_sk/'.$skl->id_ptk,' ',array('i class'=>'btn btn-success btn-sm icon fa fa  fa-print '))." </td>
              <?php else:?>
              <td >".anchor('ptk2/cetak_one_sk/'.$skl->id_ptk,' ',array('i class'=>'btn btn-success btn-sm icon fa fa  fa-print disabled '))." </td>
              <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: is that your problem was the php code in echo not running?

Comment: not but, both buttons are active

Comment: try this `echo '<tr><td>$no</td>
                      <td>$skl->nama_ptk</td>
              <td>$skl->no_sk_kepsek</td>
                      <td >$skl->status_sk</td>'.(($status=='SK TERBIT')?'fa-print':'fa-print disabled');`

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed php code with html code, it should display an error.
On your `if` condition, you could change it like below :

```
    <?php
      foreach ($record->result() as $skl) {
          ...
          if ($status=='SK TERBIT'):
          echo "<td >".anchor('ptk2/cetak_one_sk/'.$skl->id_ptk,'<i class="fa fa-print"></i>',array('class'=>'btn btn-success btn-sm icon'))." </td>";
          else:
          echo "<td >".anchor('ptk2/cetak_one_sk/'.$skl->id_ptk,'<i class="fa fa-print"></i>',array('class'=>'btn btn-success btn-sm icon disabled'))." </td>";
          endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: look closely, OP's code is calling PHP variable outside the `<?php ?>` tags.., also by separating the code it will be easier to read

Answer (score 0):

You can try this without mixed code

```
foreach ($record->result() as $skl) {
   $status=$skl->status_sk;
   echo "<tr><td>$no</td>
             <td>$skl->nama_ptk</td>
             <td>$skl->no_sk_kepsek</td>
             <td >$skl->status_sk</td>".
   (($status=='SK TERBIT')?'<td >'.anchor('ptk2/cetak_one_sk/'.$skl->id_ptk,' ',array('i class'=>'btn btn-success btn-sm icon fa fa  fa-print ')).' </td>':'<td >'.anchor('ptk2/cetak_one_sk/'.$skl->id_ptk,' ',array('i class'=>'btn btn-success btn-sm icon fa fa  fa-print disabled ')).' </td>');
}
```